# How to search in json array object with laravel query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is json array

```
"section_4": {
"data": [
{
"grade": "3.0",
"degree": "BSCSE",
"end_date": "2019-03-28T10:35:00.000Z",
"institute": "DIU",
"start_date": "2019-03-25T10:35:00.000Z"
},
{
"grade": "4.0",
"degree": "BSCSE",
"end_date": "2019-04-30T10:50:00.000Z",
"institute": "STU",
"start_date": "2019-03-31T10:50:00.000Z"
}
],
"type": "education",
"title": "Educations"
},
```

Want to search with grade, is it possible to search with query builder?

```
$resumes = UserMeta::with(['user.resume' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('data->section_4->type', 'like', '%education%');
        }])->paginate(10);
```

Here is code to try to search in controller. is it possible to search with grade with query builder laravel?

Answer (score 5):

For search in json array in laravel you can use this :
for example you want check value in "grade" from "data" array :

```
$resumes = UserMeta::with(['user.resume' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereJsonContains('data->data', ['grade' => "3.0"]);
    }])->paginate(10);
```

Done....

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! it works! Do you have a way to use `like` with this method ?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel offers [`whereJsonContains`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) so you can try the below code:

```
$resumes = UserMeta::with(['user.resume' => function ($query) {
                $query->whereJsonContains('data->section_4->type', 'like', '%education%');
        }])->paginate(10);
```

**OR**
you can also use `whereRaw` with the combination of `JSON_CONTAINS` in this case:

e.g

```
whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(type, '[education]' )")->get();
```

For more check this [post](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/)

Comment: Here got all the array object of education->data; want to search data->grade and institute

Comment: Got education data. Can i search with every grade and institute? @iftikhar uddin

Comment: @ShunhraSarker yes why not! It should be something like `data->section_4->data['grade']` or `data->section_4->data->grade`

Comment: Here data can be multiple inside education. Is it work for multiple data without foreach loop?

Comment: @ShunhraSarker How did you manage to solve the loop?